# How can I fill dots with different colors while positioning them according to another group in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping, fill

I have a data set in which different genotypes went through different testing conditions. These were done in multiple different cohorts. I, therefore, want to make a dot plot that distinguishes between the different genotypes. I also want each dots within each genotype group to have a color representing which cohort they are coming from.

I created a dataset as an example:

```
Y<-c(2,3,1,6,4,5,3,3,4)
X<-c('test','test','test','test','control','control','control','test','control')
Cohort <- c("first", "Second", "Second", "Second", "Second", "first", "Second","Second", "first")
Genotype<-c("WT","WT","WT","Mutant","Mutant","Mutant","Mutant","WT","WT")

DF<-data.frame(X,Y,Cohort,Genotype)
DF

ggplot(DF, aes(x=X, y=Y, group= X:Genotype)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", binwidth = 0.5, stroke= 3, aes(colour= Genotype, fill = Cohort), position = position_dodge(1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("light blue", "blue"))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orange",  "purple"))
```

When I execute this code, I get a graph similar to the desired one. However, some dots are left blank instead of being colored according to the cohort.

[Here is the graph with some dots unfilled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJwfM.png)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should remove `group` in your `aes`. 
Here, an example:

```r
ggplot(DF, aes(x = X, y = Y, fill = Cohort, color = Genotype))+
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 10, position = position_jitter(0.2), stroke = 2)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("light blue", "blue"))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orange",  "purple"))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = c("light blue", "blue"), color = c(NA,NA))))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

---

**EDIT: Separating WT/Mutant Control/Test**

If you want to separate x values based on the treatment and the genotype, you can use `interaction` to create 4 x values based on the treatment and genotype:

```r
ggplot(DF, aes(x = interaction(X,Genotype), y = Y, fill = Cohort, color = Genotype))+
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 10, stroke = 2, position = position_dodge2(0.5))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("light blue", "blue"))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orange",  "purple"))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = c("light blue", "blue"), color = c(NA,NA))))
```

[image]

An another posibility is to facet the graph using `facet_wrap`:

```r
ggplot(DF, aes(x = Genotype, y = Y, fill = Cohort, color = Genotype))+
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 10, stroke = 2, position = position_dodge2(0.5))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("light blue", "blue"))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orange",  "purple"))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = c("light blue", "blue"), color = c(NA,NA))))+
  facet_wrap(~X, strip.position = "bottom")+
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(-1,"lines"),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: The coloring is perfect. However, is it possible to keep that coloring while aligning the mutant/control together, the mutant/test together, the WT/control together, and another column with the WT/test together?

Comment: Ok, so 4 columns ?

Comment: If it is possible it would be two columns: control and test. Then, each column would be subdivided: mutant vs WT.

Comment: I have edited my answer, let me know if it is close to what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. Let me know if it is what you are looking for.